# Следующий элемент по типу после текущего

Tags: jquery

Как найти элемент по типу, в пределах формы, после текущего элемента?

Например:

```
<form>
    <input id="f"/>
    <input id="s"/>
    <div>
         <div>
              <input id="t"/>
         </div>
    </div>
    <input id="ff">
</form>
```

Как мне, находясь на элементе id=t, перешагнуть на следующий тип input, в нашем случае id=ff? ID заранее неизвестен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/seyari/1/edit?html,js,console

```
function nextInput(inp) {
  var elems = inp.form.elements;
  return elems[[].indexOf.call(elems, inp)+1];
}

console.log(nextInput(f).id); // s
console.log(nextInput(t).id); // ff
```

P.S. Но скорей всего вам нужен http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/tabindex

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо! Tabindex не нужен, т.к. перемещение идет не по индексу.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $forms = $('#t').closest('form').find('input');
```

Все инпуты в этой форме, выбирайте по индексу, типа `$forms.eq(1)`

А ещё лучше если ID неизвестен тогда задайте тим всем одинаквый класс, например `"js-forms"` и получите все формы так:

```
var $froms = $('.js-forms');
```

Если хотите "валидацию" то можно использовать дата атрибут, скажем так:

```
<input data-validate="email" />
<input data-validate="text" />
<input data-validate="text" />
```

И далее получаем массив только тех форм которые нужно "отвалидировать":

```
var $forms = $('[data-validate]');

$.each($forms.function(i,form){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisValue = $this.val();
    var thisType = $this.attr('data-validate');

    console.log([$thisValue,thisType ]);
});
```

Очень удобно в обработке, на событе "родительской формы" `submit()`

Если данные "костыли" нужны для перемещания по инпутам при помощи кнопки `tab` используйте атрибут `tabindex` как-то так:

```
<input tabindex="1" />
<input tabindex="2" />
<input tabindex="3" />
<input type="submit" tabindex="4" />
```

Comment: Олег, спасибо за развернутый ответ, но, если применить `$('#t').closest('form').find('input');`, я попаду на первый input, где id=f. Как видно из моего вопроса, меня интересует следующий input после текущего.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто поскакать по DOM-дереву. Чтобы находясь на элементе id=t попасть на следующий input, используйте эту строку:

```
$('#t').parent().parent().next()
```

Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/p3xu6tb2/

Comment: Иерархия неизвестна заранее